# SQL query select count from table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like :

```
id_cat  id_city 
1   33
1   33
1   33
2   44
2   33
2   55
```

and i want to obtain a result like :

```
id_cat id_city cat_count 
1      33      3  
2      44      1
2      33      1
2      55      1
```

how can i build my query ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` which is an aggregate function and a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT  id_cat, id_city, COUNT(*) cat_Count
FROM    tableName 
GROUP   BY id_cat, id_city
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56b40/1)